# VueJS input numbers and on button click redirect to link with input number

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to do the following: added to `input` field `v-model`, and I want to pass the entered numbers to the `button`, so that when clicked, it will redirect to the page with the entered numbers.

I do it like this:

```
<input v-model="check_id" type="text" placeholder="Write numbers">
<button :href="'https:/example.com/' + check_id"> Redirect  </button>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      loaded: false,
     
      check_id: "",
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

And when i write numbers, for example 123, and click to `Redirect` nothing happens. H

How i can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use anchor element `a` which has the `href` attribute :

```
<button >
   <a :href="'https:/example.com/' + check_id">
     Redirect 
    </a>
 </button>
```